# Error creating shaded jar: Problem shading JAR java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I created fat jar(common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) using maven shade plugin. It generated successfully. This common dependency include to new maven project and try to generate fat jar. But it given above error. I tried with different answers as exclude MANIFEST files. After excluding MANIFEST files it asked to exclude .class files in common.jar library.

Need I use any signing method to common library or is there any way to ignore this error.
Thank you.

**common library pom.xl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jakson-version>2.9.2</jakson-version>
        <protobuf-version>3.2.0</protobuf-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.7.14</slf4j-version>
        <bigtable-version>1.13.0</bigtable-version>
        <hbase-version>2.2.3</hbase-version>
        <pubsub-version>1.103.0</pubsub-version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
        <netty-version>2.0.29.Final</netty-version>
        <grpc-netty-shaded-version>1.27.1</grpc-netty-shaded-version>
        <netty-codec-http2-version>4.1.45.Final</netty-codec-http2-version>
        <os-maven-plugin-version>1.5.0.Final</os-maven-plugin-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <protobuf-maven-plugin-version>0.5.0</protobuf-maven-plugin-version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin-version>2.21.0</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
        <rabbit-mq-version>5.8.0</rabbit-mq-version>
        <spark-core-version>2.7.1</spark-core-version>
        <slf4j-simple-version>1.7.7</slf4j-simple-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jakson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jakson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
            <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-2.x-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>${bigtable-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hbase-shaded-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-shaded-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hbase-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
            <version>${pubsub-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>${rabbit-mq-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spark-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-simple-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${os-maven-plugin-version}</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${protobuf-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.6.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.4.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**new project pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>new-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.MF</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with spring-boot-maven-plugin.